# Cassandra write performance regarding consistency level

Tags: nosql, cassandra

Here is quote from cassandra documentation about writes ([LINK](http://www.datastax.com/docs/0.8/dml/about_writes#about-transactions))

> If all replicas for the affected row key are down, it is still
>   possible for a write to succeed if using a write consistency level of
>   ANY. Under this scenario, the hint and written data are stored on the
>   coordinator node, but will not be available to reads until the hint
>   gets written to the actual replicas that own the row. The ANY
>   consistency level provides absolute write availability at the cost of
>   consistency, as there is no guarantee as to when written data will be
>   available to reads (depending how long the replicas are down). **Using
>   the ANY consistency level can also potentially increase load on the
>   cluster, as coordinator nodes must temporarily store extra rows
>   whenever a replica is not available to accept a write.**

My question is: is writing to cassandra slower if we use consistency level of **ANY** than writes when we use consistency level of **ONE** ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hints are generated when appropriate replica nodes are inaccessible at write time.  Write requests are then serialized locally on the request coordinator node.  Once a valid replica node becomes available and the coordinator node learns of it, the request is passed along to the newly available replica.

With that background, there are two write-time scenarios to consider:

1) **At least one replica is up for the affected row**.  In this case, there is no difference between consistency levels of `ANY` and `ONE`.  The write just goes to the replica(s), and hinted handoff is not triggered.  **No performance difference**.

2) **All replicas are down for the affected row**.  This is where hints enter the picture.  With consistency `ANY` there is extra work to be done on the coordinator node at request time, as the hint is written to a local system table for later replay.  With consistency `ONE`, you would simply get a refused write in the same circumstances.  **`ONE` will expose write failures to the client, and will be faster than `ANY`**.

Essentially, the tradeoff is refusing requests vs. pushing work onto remaining nodes, but *only when nodes responsible for storing that row are down*.

Comment: That was it, thanks...i was not sure if those hints happen all the time or just in case 2 ... it makes sense :)